# I want to run my Android Virtual Device using Hardware - GLES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-virtual-device

I want to run Android Virtual Device using Hardware - GLES 2.0 but every time I do so, the following error shows up:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edz3x.png)

And also this error code shows up in the event log:

```
2020-06-15
3:24 PM Gradle sync started

3:25 PM Gradle sync finished in 46 s 992 ms

3:25 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

3:25 PM * daemon started successfully

3:31 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Albert John\AndroidStudioProjects\HappyBirthday

3:31 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I am using a laptop with specs of:

- Intel 17-7700HQ CPU
- 16 GB of RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile

I also connected my laptop to an external display and external GPU (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti) using Razer Core.

Please let me know what fixes I can do. Thank you!

Comment: Don't know what that exit code stands for; please provide more than just the last line.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I just updated the screenshot of the error message and the information in the event log. Please let me know what else should I add. Thank you!